# Django Q&Q versus filter.filter

Tags: sql, django, orm

While hunting a bug, I found out that the following 2 statements do different things:

**Query 1**

```
Order.objects \
  .filter(items__name__icontains="Foo") \
  .filter(items__name__icontains="Bar") \
  .distinct()
```

**Query 2**

```
Order.objects \
  .filter(
    Q(items__name__icontains="Foo") &
    Q(items__name__icontains="Bar")
  ) \
  .distinct()
```

The result is as follows:

- *Query 1* does include orders that have items which *either* contain *"Foo"* or *"Bar"*. For example one item's name is *"Foo"* while another item's name is *"Bar"*.
- *Query 2* however only includes orders that have *at least one item* that contains *all keywords*, for example an item with a name of *"Foo Bar"*.

Looking at the queries, I can see that the `filter()` method adds another `INNER JOIN` to the query while the other doesn't.

I can see the reasoning behind this, but I really wonder if that's the intended behavior.

Comment: I don't know if it's intended, but it's really handy. Sometimes I want the first behaviour, and sometimes I want the second, and it's good to have a way to get either.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Absolutely, if one's aware of the difference that is. --I did not find an info about it in Django's "Making Queries" documentation, that's why I'm wondering.-- See the answer, it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first query has two `filter()` calls, and the second query only has one.

The first query tries to find an object with a related item containing 'Foo' and a related item containing 'Bar'. The second query tries to find an item with a single related item that contains both 'Foo' and 'Bar'

The fact that one uses `Q()` objects is not significant - you could change the first query to:

```
Order.object.filter(
    Q(items__name__icontains="Foo"
).filter(
    Q(items__name__icontains="Bar")
)
```

However the `Q()` is required in your second `Query 2`m since it would be invalid Python to repeat the keyword argument in `.filter(items__name__icontains="Foo", items__name__icontains="Bar")`

See the docs on [spanning multi-values relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) for more info.